# Disappearing <li> content. Alternating

Tags: html, css

The CSS and the HTML code below generate

```
News
Interviews
----------------------
Djing
Break dance
----------------------
```

Why does the horizontal line disappear?

The height of each `<li>` was changed up to 53px, but it did not give the needed effect.
If `<hr>` is inserted instead of the `<div>` horizontal_line_rule, it always appears.

```
div#footer{
    /*font-family: PTSerifNarrow, sans-serif;*/
    /*background-color: #e6e6e6;*/
    background-color: #050505;
    height: 23.75em;
    clear: both;
}
div#footer a{
    color: inherit;
}
div#footer span{
    color: #8f8f8f;
}
/* 9.03.2014. Edited. */
div#footer > div#footer-container{
    padding: 0 6.875em;
    /*padding-top: 1.312em;*/
    padding-top: 2.624em;
    padding-right: 1.312em; 
    width: 1380px;
    background-color: #050505;
}
div#footer-container > ul > li{
    display: block; 
    color: white;
    font-family: Proxima Nova, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
}
div.horizontal_line_rule{
    clear: both;
    width: 10%;
    background-color: #696969;
    opacity: 0.2;
    filter: alpha(opacity=20); /* For IE8 and earlier. */
    height: 0.5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
div#footer-container > ul > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```
<div id = "footer">
    <div id = "footer-container">
        <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="/">News</a>
            <div class = "horizontal_line_rule"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="../interviews">Interviews</a>
            <div class = "horizontal_line_rule"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="../djing">Djing</a>
            <div class = "horizontal_line_rule"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="../break-dance">Break dance</a>
            <div class = "horizontal_line_rule"></div>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Additionally, how to display several such lists in a line?

Comment: What do you mean when you ask why the horizontal line disappears? Are you looking for it to extend across the entire width of the page?

Comment: 0.5px is not a valid pixel height :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure here, but I highly suspect it's cause you've asked for a half-pixel height. The smallest a PC can display is a pixel, by definition, so it really can't do what you've asked for and you'd likely get either 1px or 0px depending on rounding & background logic you can't control.

Turn it up to 1px and it should be more consistent. If you don't want it to look that solid you'll have to go a lighter gray cause it just can't do half a pixel.

Answer (score 2):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/capok/1/edit)**

Use     `height: 1px;` for your `.horizontal_line_rule`

instead of the `0.5px`

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of cleaning up the code, you might consider just adding a solid 1px `border-bottom` class to any `li` that needs it. Just a suggestion.